# Compiling webkit on windows : environment variable not found $(PRODUCTION)

Tags: webkit, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile webkit on windows and am running into several errors.
One of them is :

The following environment variables were not found: $(PRODUCTION)

Does anybody know what this variable is supposed to map to?

Thanks
-M

Answer (score 0):

This warning is normal in the development environment and should not result in any real build errors. You are looking for something more severe.